# using pointers to display elements from a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

Hi Im just starting to get my head around pointers and arrays and Ive more or less know how to manipulate pointers in a one dimensional arrays to display the elements. But how about in multidimensional arrays?
I have been practicing with this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int a[2][3]= { {1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0]; // or (*ptr)[3] = a;

    cout <<"Adress 0,0: "<< a << endl;
    cout <<"Adress 0,0: "<< ptr << endl;         
    cout <<"Value 0,0: "<< *a[0] << endl;
    cout <<"Value 0,0: "<< *(ptr)[0]<< endl;
    cout <<"Adress 0,1: "<< &a[0][1] << endl;
    cout <<"Adress 0,1: "<< (ptr)[1] << endl;       

    return 0;
}
```

I have managed to display the address and value of a[0][0] using the array name and the pointer, but how to display the address and value of a[0][1] and the succeeding elements by using the pointer?

Comment: `(ptr)[1]` doesn't point to `a[0][1]`, it points to `a[1][0]`.

Comment: I think you're trying to hit `(*ptr)[1]` if you're looking to deliver the value `2` from your array of arrays. The address of that element is  simply `(*ptr)+1` (or, if you want to be long-winded, `*(ptr+0) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(ptr)[1]` (same as `ptr[1]`) doesn't point to `a[0][1]`, it points to `a[1][0]` because you defined `ptr` as a pointer to `int[3]`, not `int`. Therefore incrementing `ptr` by `1` with `ptr[1]` skips three `int`s, up to `a[1][0]`.

To increment `ptr` by the size of one `int` instead of three `int`s:

```
ptr[0] + 1
```

The above will point to `a[0][1]`. And to access that:

```
*(ptr[0] + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @zenith for clarifying. Yup my previous code pointed (or skipped) 3 ints ahead thats why it printed 4 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()

{

    int a[2][3]= { {1,2,3},{4,5,6}  };
    int (*ptr)[3] = &a[0]; // or (*ptr)[3] = a;

    cout <<"Adress 0,0: "<< a << endl;
    cout <<"Adress 0,0: "<< ptr << endl;         
    cout <<"Value 0,0: "<< *a[0] << endl;
    cout <<"Value 0,0: "<< *((ptr)[0]+0)<< endl;
    cout <<"Adress 0,1: "<< &a[0][1] << endl;
    cout <<"Adress 0,1: "<< (ptr)[0]+1 << endl;       
    cout <<"value 0,1: "<<  a[0][1] << endl;
    cout <<"value 0,1: "<< *((ptr)[0]+1) << endl;

    cout <<"Adress 1,0: "<< &a[1][0] << endl;
    cout <<"Adress 1,0: "<< (ptr)[1] << endl;       
    cout <<"value 1,0: "<<  a[1][0] << endl;
    cout <<"value 1,0: "<< *((ptr)[1]+0) << endl;       

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I now understand how to traverse a 2 dimension array using pointers.